# Should I postpone the NINO meeting until I have a stable home?

Tags: united-kingdom, working, paperwork, insurance

I have a meeting for the National Insurance Number this Monday in the city I used to live in. But I don't have an actual proper home in the UK yet, I just moved to London. They want proof of address and I can show them my hostel bill, which had agreed. Yet I'm almost certain I'm going to move in the following weeks (in a proper home in London). Should I postpone the NINO meeting?

The meeting is in the city I used to live in before moving to this hostel. I don't know if it's better to postpone it to have it in the job center of the city I now live in.

Let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Depends. Are the hostel willing to accept your post after you've moved? And do you want to go back there to collect it?

Comment: @MJeffryes Hmm, I'm not sure. I will try to ask them at lunch break

Comment: To be clear, they would only need to accept one letter from DWP telling you your NI number.

Comment: @MJeffryes Understood, I will tell them. Should I warn NIN that I might be moving? FYI, the meeting is in the city I used to live in before moving to this hostel.

Comment: I'm not sure that's necessary, it might just create more trouble. If it were me, I'd just phone the helpline once I'd moved to tell them my new address, if the number hadn't already arrived.

Comment: @MJeffryes Okay, I will do that. And I'm going to ask the hostel now if they agree that I receive a letter once I moved. And what about giving my work address?

Comment: Not sure if DWP will accept a work address, but definitely worth asking.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to do this. A temporary address is acceptable for applying for a National Insurance Number.

After your appointment, the Department for Work and Pensions will post you a letter telling you your National Insurance Number. If you change your address after the appointment but before you get the letter [you can phone the DWP to tell them](https://www.gov.uk/apply-national-insurance-number).

> If you change your address before you get your letter, tell DWP by contacting the National Insurance number application line.
>
> **National Insurance number application line** 
>   Telephone: 0800 141 2075 
>   Textphone: 0800 141 2438 
>   Monday to Friday, 8am to 6pm

However, I wouldn't rely on this process, since it's possible that you could move after the letter is posted but before it arrives, so you should still be prepared to receive the letter at your old address.

In case it isn't clear, once you've received your National Insurance Number, there's no need to keep DWP up to date with your address (unless you have some other reason to, such as universal credit or another benefit).